# Loss stops dropping and equiprobable outputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm training my first CNN, but loss stops at 1, and its plot also shows spikes:
[enter image description here][1]
This is the code:

```
class RedClasificacion(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=3) # 64 canales, 36, 36
    self.norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
    self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=3) # 128 canales, 12, 12
    self.norm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(0.35)
    self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) # 64 canales, 6, 6
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=2, stride=2) # 256 canales, 6, 6
    self.norm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
    self.drop2 = nn.Dropout(0.35)
    self.act3 = nn.ReLU()
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) # 32 canales, 6, 6
    self.flat = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(32 * 4 * 4, 128)
    self.norm4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
    self.drop3 = nn.Dropout(0.35)
    self.act4 = nn.ReLU()
    self.lin3 = nn.Linear(128, 4)
    self.softf = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
```

I'm also using this transform:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5),
    transforms.RandomRotation(180),
    transforms.RandomInvert(),
    transforms.Resize(size=(144, 144)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

The image dataset I'm using has 4 classes, each with 900 images.
And I also keep getting equiprobable outputs when infering, I get approx. 25% for each class.
Why is this happening?
Thanks.

I tried to train a CNN to classify images in 4 classes, but I'm getting ambiguous output, and the loss doesn't get lower, even when training 105 epochs.

Comment: what loss function are you using?

Comment: I'm using CrossEntropyLoss. By the way, I already removed Softmax layer from the network, as it's not necessary